# Call Oracle stored procedures from a main oracle stored procedure (syntax error)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle12c

I am trying to create a main Oracle stored procedure, calling other Oracle stored procedures. I am getting a syntax error in Toad.

The environment is Windows Server 2012R2 and the Oracle edition is 12.1.0.

The main stored procedure is simple:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTDB.MAIN
(
ID IN NUMBER

)
IS


BEGIN

CALL PROCEDURE1(ID);
CALL PROCEDURE2(ID);
CALL PROCEDURE3(ID);
CALL PROCEDURE4(ID);


END;
```

I am getting a syntax error while compiling for each  procedure:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROCEDURE1" when
>   expecting one of the following:
>
> := . ( @ % ; The symbol ":=" was substituted for
>   "PROCEDURE1" to continue.

What is the correct syntax in order to call the procedures from one central procedure?

Comment: If you're going to be working with PL/SQL you may find it useful to bookmark the Oracle documentation which is online, comprehensive and free. You can easily answer straightforward syntax questions like this for yourself. For instance, [here is the pertinent section on calling subprograms](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS653)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove [`CALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CALL.html#GUID-6CD7B9C4-E5DC-4F3C-9B6A-876AD2C63545), that can only be used

> to execute a routine […] from within SQL

```
BEGIN
  PROCEDURE1(ID);
  PROCEDURE2(ID);
  PROCEDURE3(ID);
  PROCEDURE4(ID);
END;
```

For example:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure proc(n IN OUT number) is begin n := 10; end;
  2  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var x number
SQL> call proc(:x);

Call completed.

SQL> print :x

         X
----------
        10

SQL> declare
  2    y number;
  3  begin
  4    call proc(y);
  5  end;
  6  /
  call proc(y);
       *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 8:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROC" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "PROC" to continue.


SQL>
```